# database : storing index or key value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using PHP, MySql.

Example :

```
$type = array(
    "owner",
    "agent",
    "representative",
);
```

What is the preferrable way to store in DB ?

1. store it as index, 0 means 'Owner', 1 means 'Agent', ...
2. store it with key value. Recreate above code with

   ```
   $type = array(
       "OWNER" => "owner",
       "AGENT" => "agent",
       "REPRESENTATIVE" => "representative",
   );
   ```

   And then store the value as "OWNER", "AGENT".

I tend to use method 2, since as to me it increases readibility.

Method 1

- low readibility

+ good performance

Method 2 (ENUM)

+ high readibility

- <strike>low performance</strike>

- add key need to alter database design

What's the best practice ? What you guys use ?

Comment: I would always use an integer as the key.

Comment: You could store it as an [`enum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html). Then you've got the best of both worlds!

Comment: @Travesty3 yes, when I use method2 I store it as enum. But sometimes when want to add more type/key, I need to alter my database again. So its kind of dilemma for me whether to use method1.

Comment: VARCHAR(4) takes the same amount of bytes as INT.  VARCHAR(5+) takes more space.  The less bytes a data type takes, the better the JOIN performance.  Another advantage to using INT as a primary key is that you can add more type values if necessary.

Comment: If you store it as an enum, is there really lower performance? Without having researched it, I would think that MySQL would just store an integer value for the index of the value. No?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a relatively finite set of values, use an `ENUM` data type.  It will let you read and write in human-readable form, but behind the scenes, it will typically store it as an int.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth. But since it stores them as a bitset, be aware that it has a max of 32 or 64 values, depending on platform. (so first one is set as `1`, second as `10`, third as `100` etc)

Comment: When I want to add enum key, I'll need to alter my database again. Thats why I keep considering method1. Thx pointing me out that its stored as 16-bit.

Comment: That's the tradeoff unfortunately! I guess you've got to weigh up how often that's going to happen, and whether it's going to be worthwhile to need to execute a 1 line SQL diff when it happens.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer method 1. Performance wise it's a better option than method 2. If you're concerned about readability I would create a table called `permission_types`:

```
id | value
1    Owner
2    Agent
```

You can then join that table and have readability and performance now that you're not searching for a string. Plus, you can add more permission types with ease down the road if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is the correct way to store in a database, the answer would be index values through a process called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  Create a table of `permission_types`, and if necessary a bridge table.  If you have a table `users` you would add a table `user_permission_types` that would have a column `userID` as a foreign key to the `user` table, and a column `permissionID` as a foreign key to the `permission_types` table.  Together both of these columns would be the primary key for the `user_permission_types` table.

Doing this would eliminate all redundancy from the database.